# Wrapper for function as overloaded operator

Tags: c++, wrapper

Could you please explain me what this definition means? I see this as overloaded template function of Task structure, which calls for function with parameters `args` and casts returned result to `T` type.

```
template <class T>
struct Task
{
    template <typename ...Args>
    void operator()(const Args&... args)
    {
        (*static_cast<const T*>(this))(args...);
    }
};
```

What may be point of doing so? For me it looks very over-combined.

Comment: The point of doing so is to implement ugly, type-unsafe C++ code that nobody should be writing in the first place. No further explanation is needed.

Comment: `this` is not a function

Comment: Yes, this is address of the object, on which the member function is being called. But this confuses me even more.

Comment: Do not cast `this` to refer to a class member. Use that member's name.

Comment: This is not my code - I'm just trying to understand it completly.

Comment: So try to understand what `static_cast<const T*>(this)` means first, hint it does not cast returned result

Comment: This is the kind of code you get when you use the [Necronomicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necronomicon) as your go-to programming reference. A more sensible approach is to have an abstract base class that defines what a Task is.

Comment: This is an example of [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which can be very useful and not evil. However, I’m not sure why one would want to use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
(*static_cast<const T*>(this))(args...);
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
const T *ptr = static_cast<const T*>(this);
const T &ref = *ptr;
ref(args...);
```

I think it should be clear now what that statement does (it does not cast returned value from function call as you think)

Comment: Now it is definitely more readable. So calling `operator()` creates pointer to object and then by reference calls again overloaded `operator()`. But isn't it recurrent call of itself?

Comment: with static type `T` instead of `Task`, so usage should be `struct MyTask : Task<MyTask> { template <typename ...Args>
    void operator()(const Args&...);/*...*/};`

Comment: It does not create pointer, it casts `this` to `const T *`, so `T` suppose to be inherited from `Task<T>`